# difference between OracleBulkCopyOptions.Default and OracleBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction.

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, oracle10g, odp.net

Could anybody explain what is the difference between **OracleBulkCopyOptions.Default**  and **OracleBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction** & how i can rollback all the record if any bulk insert error happens in between.

I am using **OracleBulkCopy** to bulk insert(records range varies from 100000 to 500000 ) to Oracle data base. My requirement is either all the records should insert into db or none of the record should insert into db(roll back all records). I am giving 25000 as **BatchSize** & 150 seconds as **BulkCopyTimeout**. Below is my current code block.

```
public bool WriteExcelDataToServerRouteOne(DataTable excelTable)
        {
            var columnMapping = from table in excelTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() select new OracleBulkCopyColumnMapping(table.ColumnName, table.ColumnName);
            using (var bulkcopy = new OracleBulkCopy(ConnectionString, OracleBulkCopyOptions.Default))
            {
                bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = DestinationTable;
                foreach (var mapping in columnMapping)
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapping);
                bulkcopy.BulkCopyTimeout = TimeOut.Value;
                bulkcopy.BatchSize = BatchSize.Value;
                bulkcopy.WriteToServer(excelTable);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OracleBulkCopy doesn't support transaction for all the records, it only support transaction for batches if `UseInternalTransaction` is specified.

From [OracleBulkCopy Class](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/OracleBulkCopyClass.htm)

> - If BatchSize > 0 and the **UseInternalTransaction bulk copy option is specified**, **each batch of the bulk copy operation occurs within a
>     transaction**. If the connection used to perform the bulk copy
>     operation is already part of a transaction, an
>     InvalidOperationException exception is raised.
> - If BatchSize > 0 and the UseInternalTransaction option is not specified, rows are sent to the database in batches of size BatchSize,
>     but no transaction-related action is taken.

For your question:

> Could anybody explain what is the difference between
>   OracleBulkCopyOptions.Default and
>   OracleBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction

Default: Doesn't uses transaction for batches. 
UseInternalTransaction: Supports transaction for batches if the batch size is greater than 0.

See:
[OracleBulkCopyOptions Enumeration](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/OracleBulkCopyOptionsEnumeration.htm)

Comment: any idea what is the maximum BatchSize that support OracleBulkCopy ? if the record count is 500000 &  if i give excelTable.Rows.Count as BatchSize will it work ?

Comment: @user1887523, I am not sure about it. You may have to look at the documentation for that.